# Появление странных символов в конце строки

Tags: c, строки, парсер, clang

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь записать в **переменную** имя **переменной** (простите за тавтологию) из **конфигурационного файла**. Столкнулся с тем, что при выводе имени непосредственно в цикле все печатается правильно, а если записать все в переменную, то в конце строки выводяться лишние символы, цифры и другие загогулины.
Вот содержимое конфигурационного файла:

```
// This is comment.

float  f_num = 3.14            // Float number
int    num   = 10              // Integer number
char   chr   = 'S'             // Char
bool   is    = true            // Boolean
string str   = "Some string."  // String
```

Вот код на **Си**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void get_variable_value(const uint8_t* _variable_name, const FILE* _cfg_file) {
    uint8_t  current_str[101];
    uint8_t  var_name[30];
    uint32_t j = 0;

    while (fgets(current_str, sizeof(current_str), _cfg_file)) {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < strlen(current_str); ++i) {
            if (current_str[i] == '/' && current_str[i+1] == '/') break;
            if (strlen(current_str) == 0) break;

            if (current_str[i] == 'i' && current_str[i+1] == 'n' && current_str[i+2] == 't') {
                uint32_t k = i+3;

                while (current_str[k] == ' ') k++;

                while (current_str[k] != ' ') {     // Вот 
                    printf("%c", current_str[k]);   //   тот
                    var_name[j] = current_str[k];   //     самый
                    k++;                            //       цикл
                    j++;                            //        .
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    printf("\n%s\n", var_name);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    const FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    get_variable_value("var", file);
    return 0;
}
```

Вот что печатает:

```
eanmos@eanmos-pc:~/.projects$ ./bin/main bin/file.cfg 
num
nu�o
```

Компилирую так: `clang-3.6 -std=c11 src/main.c -o bin/main`

**Операционная система**: *Lubuntu 15.04*

**Компилятор**: *Clang-3.6*

Comment: Отладчик что показывает?

Comment: А кто за Вас `'\0'` в конец строки будет дописывать? Странно, что не крашится еще.

Comment: До кучи, `j` в начеле внешнего `while` было бы неплохо обнулить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, ИМХО, в код нужно ввести 2 исправления

```
while (fgets(...)) {
   j = 0; // 1) иначе следующее имя будет писаться не с начала массива var_name
   ...
   while (current_str[k] != ' ') {
      ...
   }
   var_name[j] = '\0';  // 2) иначе printf не сможет напечатать var_name
   ...
   printf("\n%s\n", var_name);
}
```

и в обоих проверках, вместо `break` напишите `continue`, тогда у Вас выведутся все имена переменных из конфиг-файла.

Answer (score 0):

> А кто за Вас `'\0'` в конец строки будет дописывать? Странно, что не крашится еще.
>   – **[andy.37](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/192530/andy-37)**

Спасибо, все работает!